# I checked other answers of Project Euler's 11 but I couldn't understand. Can someone check what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: python

Ok, so I'm a complete amateur in Python. I know this code is not good nor is it correct. But it makes sense to me. I wanted to see what I'm doing wrong.

Since I have to find the max product of 4 adjacent numbers in this grid, I just made it go through each number and calculate the 3 adjacent numbers in all directions, append it to a list and then I'll just use `max()` to find what I want.

As even I would expect this is very slow to the point my laptop froze the two times I tried runnning it so I'd like to see why others make more sense than this and specially how do nested for loops account for diagonal numbers.

```
gridlist = '08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08 \
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00 \
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65 \
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91 \
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80 \
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50 \
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70 \
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21 \
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72 \
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95 \
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92 \
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57 \
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58 \
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40 \
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66 \
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69 \
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36 \
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16 \
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54 \
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48'


def multdirec(lista):
    List = lista.split()
    gridlist = [int(x) for x in List]
    resProd = []
    x = 0
    while x < len(List):
        for x in range(0,401):        
            VU = gridlist[x] * gridlist[x - 20]  * gridlist[x - 40] * gridlist[x - 60]
            resProd.append(VU)
            VD = gridlist[x] * gridlist[x + 20] * gridlist[x + 40] * gridlist[x + 60]
            resProd.append(VD)
            HL = gridlist[x] * gridlist[x - 1] * gridlist[x - 2] * gridlist[x - 3]
            resProd.append(HL)
            HR = gridlist[x] * gridlist[x + 1]  * gridlist[x + 2]  * gridlist[x + 3]
            resProd.append(HR)
            DLD = gridlist[x] * gridlist[x + 19] * gridlist[x + 38] * gridlist[x + 57]
            resProd.append(DLD)
            DLU = gridlist[x] * gridlist[x - 21] * gridlist[x - 42] * gridlist[x -63]
            resProd.append(DLU)
            DRD = gridlist[x] * gridlist[x + 21] * gridlist[x + 42] * gridlist[x + 63]
            resProd.append(DRD)
            DRU = gridlist[x] * gridlist[x - 19] * gridlist[x - 38] * gridlist[x - 57]
            resProd.append(DRU)
    return resProd

  multdirec(gridlist)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect you'll have an easier time reasoning about your code if you convert the grid into a two dimensional list (a list of lists, where every interior list is a row in the grid).  It also seems that you're keeping every product you generate.  You should only be keeping the largest product you have encountered.

Comment: I saw people do that but I don't see why a list of lists can be any different since(it seems like) it only changes how I address the elements of the lists.

Comment: @GabrielAlmeida It greatly simplifies how you address the elements, making it much easier to test for edge cases and adjacency.  Right now the indices you're using, beyond being incorrect on many edge cases, are based on knowing the exact dimensions of the input in advance.  With a 2-dimensional array, adjacency across rows is much easier to compute, and can use the same index values and edge case checks regardless of the size of the array

Comment: I can see it now. Instead of moving only horizontally, with 2d matrix I can move vertically too. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script does not finish since the while loop is never getting false.

I don't see the reason, why you define the grid as string instead of a two dimensional list (list of lists) containing integers. As well using the numpy library, which provide 2d-matrices can simplify this.

Looping through nested list of integers (just a part of your values as an example), like you have done for the string:

```
grid = [[8, 2, 22, 97, 38],
        [49, 49, 99, 40, 70],
        [81, 49, 31, 73, 55],
        [52, 70, 95, 23, 4]]
products = []

for i in range(len(grid)):  # looping the rows
    for j in range(len(grid[i])):  # looping the cols
        if i+3 < len(grid):
            v = grid[i][j]*grid[i+1][j]*grid[i+2][j]*grid[i+3][j]
            products.append(v)
        if j+3 < len(grid[i]):
            h = grid[i][j]*grid[i][j+1]*grid[i][j+2]*grid[i][j+3]
            products.append(h)
        if i+3 < len(grid) and j+3 < len(grid[i]):
            dr = grid[i][j]*grid[i+1][j+1]*grid[i+2][j+2]*grid[i+3][j+3]
            products.append(dr)
        if j+3 < len(grid) and i-3 >= 0:
            dl = grid[i][j]*grid[i-1][j+1]*grid[i-2][j+2]*grid[i-3][j+3]
            products.append(dl)

print(max(products))  
# maximum is 24468444 took 0.002 seconds
```

It's not needed to check both directions up and down, left and right, since it's the same because `a*b*c*d = d*c*b*a`. The code can be written cleaner for sure, but this is close to your example and hopefully easy to understand.

Offtopic: You shoud avoid naming your lists `List`, because capital letters are used for classes (it's just a convention) and the name `List` is already defined for the default python class List. It works in this case since the variable name is checked before the class name in this scope, but it's better to avoid the builtin names ;).

Comment: I'm getting this `IndexError: list index out of range` on `h = grid[i][j]*grid[i][j+1]*grid[i][j+2]*grid[i][j+3]`. Strange since you seem to have checked for edge cases.

Comment: I'm getting this error no matter what. If I put `j+17` it considers the condition and jumps `h` as expected, but if I put `j+3` it does not. Also, if I make it reach `dr` I get the same exception.

Comment: My bad, the index out of range is caused in the case j+3 = len(grid) since i missed counting the 0. If len(grid) = 5 than grid[5] is already out of range. As well I mixed `i` and `j` in the `dr`-line. I edit the code, it's working now. Also added the values to the list.

Answer (score 0):

First, a basic issue: You don't need the `while` loop at all. As it is, it is harmless since the inner `for` loop (which sets the value of `x`) always runs to 400, which is the length of the list, so the `while` never repeats. But if it did, it would run forever, since there's nothing inside the `while` that could change the maximum value of `x`.

The other problems I see are with how you're indexing into your list of numbers:

One issue has to do with the bounds of the grid. Currently, your code doesn't make any effort to avoid running off the edges, which means the grid effectively wraps around, some of the time. At the start, that's because Python allows negative indexes, which count from the end of the list instead of from the start. In this situation though it doesn't really work, even if you do want to treat the top and bottom rows as adjacent. The horizontal rows will be offset when you just index off the end of a line, and the vertical wrapping only works from top to bottom, not bottom to top (indexing off the end of a list gives an error). Assuming you're not supposed to wrap around, you should check if you're too close to an edge before trying to index to get a set of adjacent values. For instance, you could check `if x % 20 > 3` before checking to your left, and `if x > 59` before checking upwards.

The other issue is redundancy. If you check the numbers starting with your first `08` and going to the right, you'll get the same product again later when you start at `97` and go left. You only need one of those. You should only need to check up to four directions from each number, with the other four being covered by another number and *ending* at the current spot. So for instance, you could check left, up, up-left and up-right. The down and right sets (and the diagonals that go down) will be handled later by the end number, coming back towards the current number.

Comment: Very insightful answer! The redundancy part was one of my questions and I got it thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

- First thing I notice is you're not checking for edge cases, for example on your first iteration with x=0, your `VU` value would be `gridlist[0] * gridlist[-20] * gridlist[-40] * gridlist[-60]` - negative indices ARE allowed in python, they are treated as indexed from the end of the array, but unless you are intentionally treating the grid as though it wraps around, that's clearly not what you meant by 'adjacent' values, so you need to check your edge cases to avoid performing unnecessary calculations.
- Second, your array index math seems off in half of your cases.  Consider the case `DLD = gridlist[x] * gridlist[x + 19] * gridlist[x + 38] * gridlist[x + 57]` and again look at the x = 0 case.  Given your 20x20 array, these are the actual items you'd end up using for the multiplication in that case:

  ```
  0 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 19
  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 38 .
  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 57 . .
  ```
- Third, consider that you're doing unnecessary repetitions of many of your calculations.

  `VU = gridlist[x] * gridlist[x - 20]  * gridlist[x - 40] * gridlist[x - 60]`

  with x = 60 is the same as

  `VD = gridlist[x] * gridlist[x + 20] * gridlist[x + 40] * gridlist[x + 60]`

  with x = 0
- Fourth, if your goal is to find the maximum product, it's unnecessary to store every result in a new list and then call max() on that at the end.  Initialize a 'max' value to 0, and on each iteration compare the current result to the max, and update it if necessary.

Overall, your solution is made overly complicated by flattening the data into a single list.  Instead you should use a 2-dimensional list where you can do much simpler index arithmetic to find adjacent elements, and also easily check the edge cases

```
. . . . . . . . [x-1, y-1] [x-1, y] [x-1, y+1] . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . [x, y-1]   [x,y]    [x,y+1] . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . [x+1, y-1] [x+1, y] [x+1, y+1] . . . . . .
```